# How to get cell's column type in smartsheet

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I'm trying to get column type information from cells when I call GetSheet(), using Smartsheet API with C# and most of the time it's null. I read in the documentation that I can do that but am not understanding.

> Endpoints which return rows (e.g. get sheet, get row) support the
>   optional include query string parameter.
>   http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#row-include-flags

I'm not seeing an option to add the column type in my intellisense. Am I missing something?
[image]

I'm using the latest Smartsheet SDK 2.0.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column type information is returned by default for the **GetSheet()** operation, so you don't need to specify any *inclusion* flag when making the call.  (That's why you're not seeing an option for it in your intellisense.)

The following code snippet shows how to use the C# SDK to retrieve a Sheet and iterate through the columns in the sheet, printing the **Title** and **Type** of each column:

```
// Set the Access Token
Token token = new Token();
token.AccessToken = YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN;

// Use the Smartsheet Builder to create a Smartsheet
SmartsheetClient smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(token.AccessToken).Build();

// Get Sheet
long sheetId = YOUR_SHEET_ID;
Sheet sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

// Examine columns and write Title and Type for each column.
foreach (Column column in sheet.Columns)
{
    Response.Write(column.Title + ": " + column.Type.ToString() + "<br/><br/>");
}
```

Please note that there is currently a known issue (bug) with the C# SDK -- **Column.Type** is not being populated in the GetSheet() response for the 3 special column types that are present only in dependency-enabled project sheets:  DURATION, PREDECESSOR, ABSTRACT_DATETIME (i.e., start date and end date).  There's no ETA for resolution of this issue at this time.  However, you could fix it yourself by downloading the C# SDK source code from [GitHub](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-csharp-sdk) and updating the [ColumnType Enumeration](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/html/T_Smartsheet_Api_Models_ColumnType.htm) to add the 3 missing enum values:

- DURATION
- PREDECESSOR
- ABSTRACT_DATETIME

Comment: Thank you, adding the abstract_datetime enum value solved my issue.

Comment: Glad I could help, Steve.  Can you please mark my response as an accepted Answer, so that others may benefit from this info in the future?  thanks!